# How to know the network interfaces under Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

When I run `cat /etc/network/interfaces` in Ubuntu 11.04 I get the below output.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I don't see the eth0 or eth1 interfaces, but I am able to see them in the Network Tools application.

How do I configure the eth0 and eth1 from command line?

Answer (score 1):

If an interface is not in `/etc/network/interfaces`, but you *want* it to be there, then why don't you just ***add*** it there? It is a *text file*, the kind you can edit.

---

The standard tools for manual network interface configuration are **`ip`** from *iproute2* and/or **`ifconfig`** (along with `route` and `arp`) from the deprecated *net-tools*. They both allow you to change IP addresses, routes, and such. For automatic configuration via DHCPv4, either **`dhclient`** or **`dhcpcd`** can be used.

(Most of these programs are in `/sbin`, so look there if you get a "command not found".)

Answer (score 0):

To find the file where you can configure your other interfaces have a look at this file (by default on ubuntu):

```
/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

For your second question use 'ifconfig'.

Comment: Shadok, In "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf" most of the lines are commented with #. I don't see the details for eth0 and eth1. When I run "ifconfig" I see the details for lo, eth0 and eth1. I am trying to add a metric for the interfaces, so that I can add priority to the interfaces. Where are the details for eth0 and eth1 stored?

Comment: You should find a block concerning eth0 in your dhclient.conf file, if not you can copy one of the existing ones and adapt it. 'metric' is an argument to 'ifconfig', see the man for more details. Try it from the command line and if it works and you want that setting permanent add it to your dhclient.conf